# XDG_* environment variables not set in graphical login

Tags: xdg

When I login into one of the virtual consoles I have those environment variables `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR XDG_SEAT XDG_SESSION_CLASS XDG_SESSION_ID XDG_SESSION_TYPE XDG_VTNR` correctly set.

On the other hand if I login into an X session using a login manager, those variables are unset.

I'm on Debian Sid, I'm not using a standard desktop environment and the useful stuff (window manager, network, pulseaudio) is started by a `~/.xsession` file.

I suspect that I'm missing something in my `~/.xsession` file... (maybe Systemd related but I don't really know).

Comment: Please rephrase the OP so it contains a question, and provide the relevant parts of your _.xsession_ file (and also the file in which you set the variables).